# What bugs are these that are infesting my pieris and what do I do about it?

Tags: identification, bugs

These bugs are all over my Pieris. What are they? The plant is close to my house. Can they cause damage to the house or the plant? I don't see them on my other plants, but all three pierises are covered with them. 
[image: on the plant]
[image: on our BBQ]

Comment: Karen, have you used any fertilizer at all on your Pieris?  Sunlight, water, great drainage/soil and FERTILIZER are critical for us humans to provide our oh so artificial gardens.  Unfertilized plants are like plants that aren't getting enough light, the proper pH of soil...they are weakened and thus MORE susceptible to disease and insect damage.

Comment: In addition, Pieris love a lower pH.  Being near the foundation of your home or concrete walkways hampers the uptake of chemicals necessary for photosynthesis as the lime leaching from the concrete raises the pH making chemicals (nutrients) unavailable.  The color of your leaves tells me the chemistry is off.  Plants that are healthy can protect themselves.  Getting rid of the bugs won't save your plants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're Pieris (also called Andromeda) Lace Bugs, as far as I can tell, the photos are a bit fuzzy. I'm not seeing any damage on the leaves, but they're not something you particularly want around. It's a bit late for control now, the usual method is to spray with horticultural oil or insecticidal soap, beneath the leaves, around May when the nymphs  are present - what's on the plants currently are the adults. Keep a check next year, inspecting the underside of leaves regularly in spring, and spray as soon as you see nymphs crawling. More info can be found here: [Lace Bugs](http://ipm.uconn.edu/documents/raw2/Lace%20Bugs/Lace%20Bugs.php?aid=179), but unfortunately, there's no picture.

A close up image of one can be seen [here.](http://bugguide.net/node/view/873705)

You may find there are other chemical sprays available for use in your area which, if they can be used now, might (or might not) prevent the adults laying eggs for overwintering, ready to hatch around May next year.